# SSL Cert Compilation into pem file

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy

I recently purchased an SSL cert and need to setup HAProxy to use it.

The instructions from HAProxy are the following

> The certificate specified in dockercloud/haproxy or in the linked application services is a pem file, containing a private key followed by a public certificate(private key must be put before the public certificate and any extra Authority certificates, order matters).

[This article](https://jamesitlab.com/2014/07/16/configuring-an-ssl-certifcate-on-a-haproxy-load-balancer/) explains in more detail that the order should be the following...

```
—–BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—–

(Your Private Key: your_domain_name.key) —

–END RSA PRIVATE KEY—–

—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Your Primary SSL certificate:

your_domain_name.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–

—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Your Intermediate certificate: DigiCertCA.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–

—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–

(Your Root

certificate: TrustedRoot.crt)

—–END CERTIFICATE—–
```

I received the following files after purchasing the SSL cert.

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
my_domain.crt
```

As well as I have a key file from CSR generation.

I ran the following

```
cat my_key_from_csr >> my_domain.pem
cat my_domain.crt >> my_domain.pem
cat COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt >> my_domain.pem
cat AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >> my_domain.pem
```

I copied the contents of `my_domain.pem` into HAProxy `SSL_CERT` variable, but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work."  Also, what about `COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt`?  Seems like (just from the name) that this one would go right before `COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the **csr** file as part of the **pem**. The following works 100% and I am using it w/ haproxy too.

```
cat your_domain_private_key.key >> your_domain.pem
cat your_domain_issued_certificate.crt >> your_domain.pem
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt >> your_domain.pem
cat COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt >> your_domain.pem
```

It is not necessary to add the Root CA (AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt) to the pem file as this is pre-installed already on all computers.